# Fixing React Native error - undefined is not an object (evaluating '_useContext.state')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to implement a context to save some information in a react native application and I keep getting a red error screen when navigating to that page. The error message I keep getting is *undefined is not an object (evaluating '_useContext.state')* - there might be something that I am overlooking here, any help is appreciated.

**This is the createDateContext **

```
export default (reducer, actions, defaultValue) => {
  const Context = React.createContext();

  const Provider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, defaultValue);

    const boundActions = {};
    for (let key in actions) {
      boundActions[key] = actions[key](dispatch);
    }

    return (
      <Context.Provider value={{ state, ...boundActions }}>
        {children}
      </Context.Provider>
    );
  };

  return { Context, Provider };
};
```

**This is the context file**

```
const certificateReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'change_title':
      return { ...state, title: action.payload };
    case 'change_description':
      return { ...state, description: action.payload };
    case 'change_phoneNumber':
      return { ...state, phoneNumber: action.payload };
    case 'change_image':
      return { ...state, changeImage: action.payload };
    case 'add_completed_date':
      return { ...state, completedDate: action.payload };
    case 'add_expiration_date':
      return { ...state, expirationDate: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const changeTitle = dispatch => title => {
  dispatch({ type: 'change_title', payload: title });
};

const changeDescription = dispatch => description => {
  dispatch({ type: 'change_description', payload: description });
};

const changePhoneNumber = dispatch => phoneNumber => {
  dispatch({ type: 'change_phoneNumber', payload: phoneNumber });
};

const changeCompletedDate = dispatch => completedDate => {
  dispatch({ type: 'add_completed_date', payload: completedDate });
};

const changeExpirationDate = dispatch => expirationDate => {
  dispatch({ type: 'add_expiration_date', payload: expirationDate });
};

export const { Context, Provider } = createDataContext(
  certificateReducer,
  {
    changeTitle,
    changeDescription,
    changeImage,
    changePhoneNumber,
    changeCompletedDate,
    changeExpirationDate
  },
  {
    title: '',
    description: '',
    image: '',
    phoneNumber: '',
    completedDate: '',
    expirationDate: ''
  }
);
```

**this is my save hook**

```
import { Context as CertificationContext } from '../context/CertificationContext';
import { Context as CertificateInfoContext } from '../context/CertificateInfoContext';
import { navigate } from '../navigationRef';

export default () => {
  const { createCertification } = useContext(CertificationContext);
  const {
    state: {
      title,
      description,
      image,
      phoneNumber,
      completedDate,
      expirationDate
    }
  } = useContext(CertificateInfoContext);

  const saveCertification = async () => {
    await createCertification(
      title,
      description,
      image,
      phoneNumber,
      completedDate,
      expirationDate
    );
    navigate('List');
  };

  return [saveCertification];
};
```

**This is the form component for saving the data**

```
import { StyleSheet, TextInput, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import ImageUpload from '../components/ImageUpload';
import DatePicker from '../components/DatePicker';
import ToggleForm from '../components/ToggleForm';
import { Context as CertificateInfoContext } from '../context/CertificateInfoContext';
import useSaveCertification from '../hooks/useSaveCertification';

const CertificationForm = () => {
  const {
    state: {
      title,
      description,
      image,
      phoneNumber,
      completedDate,
      expirationDate
    },
    changeTitle,
    changeDescription,
    changeImage,
    changePhoneNumber,
    changeCompletedDate,
    changeExpirationDate
  } = useContext(CertificateInfoContext);
  const [saveCertification] = useSaveCertification();
  const [showCompleted, setCompletedShow] = useState(false);
  const [showExpiration, setExpirationShow] = useState(false);

  return (
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#eff1f8', height: '100%' }}>
      <TextInput
        autoCapitalize='none'
        autoCorrect={false}
        style={styles.inputStyle}
        placeholder='Title'
        value={title}
        onChangeText={changeTitle}
      />

      <TextInput
        autoCapitalize='none'
        autoCorrect={false}
        style={styles.descriptionStyle}
        placeholder='Description'
        value={description}
        multiline={true}
        onChangeText={changeDescription}
      />

      <DatePicker
        name='Completed Date'
        dateVal='completedDate'
        date={completedDate}
        setDate={changeCompletedDate}
        show={showCompleted}
        setShow={setCompletedShow}
      />
      <DatePicker
        name='Expiration Date'
        dateVal='expirationDate'
        date={expirationDate}
        setDate={changeExpirationDate}
        show={showExpiration}
        setShow={setExpirationShow}
      />

      <TextInput
        autoCapitalize='none'
        autoCorrect={false}
        style={styles.inputStyle}
        placeholder='Phone Number'
        value={phoneNumber}
        onChangeText={changePhoneNumber}
      />
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', margin: 15, height: 100 }}>
        <ImageUpload
          certificationImage={image}
          setCertificationImage={changeImage}
        />
        <View style={{ paddingTop: 10 }}>
          <Text style={styles.topText}>Attach or take a picture of any</Text>
          <Text style={styles.middleText}>certification provided at</Text>
          <Text style={styles.endText}>completion</Text>
        </View>
      </View>

      <Button title='save' color='#fff' onPress={saveCertification} />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  inputStyle: {
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 5,
    alignContent: 'center',
    marginLeft: 15,
    marginRight: 15,
    marginTop: 10,
    paddingLeft: 10
  },
  descriptionStyle: {
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 5,
    alignContent: 'center',
    marginLeft: 15,
    marginRight: 15,
    marginTop: 10,
    paddingLeft: 10
  },
  topText: {
    marginLeft: 40,
    marginTop: 15,
    color: '#687089',
    fontWeight: '500'
  },
  middleText: {
    marginLeft: 60,
    color: '#687089',
    fontWeight: '500'
  },
  endText: {
    marginLeft: 100,
    color: '#687089',
    fontWeight: '500'
  }
});

export default CertificationForm;
```

Comment: `const certificateInfoContext = useContext(CertificateInfoContext); console.log(certificateInfoContext);` what's the output?

Comment: ```Object {
  "changeCompletedDate": [Function anonymous],
  "changeDescription": [Function anonymous],
  "changeExpirationDate": [Function anonymous],
  "changeImage": [Function anonymous],
  "changePhoneNumber": [Function anonymous],
  "changeTitle": [Function anonymous],
  "state": Object {
    "completedDate": "",
    "description": "",
    "expirationDate": "",
    "image": "",
    "phoneNumber": "",
    "title": "",
  },
}```

Comment: Not sure but at the first look, it seems like the issue might be in this;
const {
    state: {
      title,
      description,
      image,
      phoneNumber,
      completedDate,
      expirationDate
    }
  } = useContext(CertificateInfoContext);
You are trying to get state object from the useContext, I think you should delete the state wrap around the  'title, description, image, phoneNumber, completedDate, expirationDate.'

Comment: Thanks guys! So the issue was that I forgot to add the CertificationContext and the CertificationInfoContext as Providers in App.js. ```export default () => {
  return (
    <CertificationProvider>
      <CertificationInfoProvider>
        <AuthProvider>
          <App
            ref={navigator => {
              setNavigator(navigator);
            }}
          />
        </AuthProvider>
      </CertificationInfoProvider>
    </CertificationProvider>
  );
};```